# Can I hide torrent details from my ISP?

Tags: torrent

I admit that I know very little about torrents. There seems to be very little point in encryption them as an ISP can detect the torrent protocol and a user might then have some explaining to do (which a search of their PC might make difficult).

My question (which shows how little I know of torrents) is this - for HTTP one can have end to end encryption, using a service such as [JAP](http://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/index_en.html) which hides the requested URl from the ISP.  Is there an equivalent for torrents? Is that what VPNs do?

If one was looking for a VPN, where would one find one which is fast, keeps no logs, has a track record of several years, and is preferably located offshore & has never revealed any details of its users?

Comment: HTTPS also hides (most of) the URL of a HTTP query from your ISP. They'll only see the IP of the remote host and possibly the preceding DNS query with the host name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a VPN would mask your HTTP requests as they would be routed through the tunnel. Unless your ISP is somehow exploiting a weakness in the VPN protocol and decrypting the traffic, they would not see the requests.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to VPN, try also to use another DNS  than your ISP's DNS too; to prevent DNS leak. There are many public ones including Google's public DNS.

Comment: Thanks. I expect that Google will be quickest (if a few ms DNS resolution time really matter, compared to page load time), but I shall also look again at OpenDNS whcih I used to use ... https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/